# How to replace a character in string using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq

for example:- replace 2 with 0 for the following input
Input: string strInput = "21212121";
Output: "01010101"

How to do it with LINQ. Note: dataType is **string**.

Comment: Linq is for querying, not for changing

Comment: Why don't you use String.Replace?

Comment: Can you provide code of your input set? Because if it's not a set of strings then there's no reason to use LINQ.

Comment: Why LINQ for this? Why not [**`String.Replace()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)??

Comment: The point is that you should first retrieve the data and then do string replacement, unless you used ef and mapped a sql function to the model.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For your interviewer

```
string output = new String(input.Select(ch => ch == '2' ? '0' : ch).ToArray());
```

I think intend was to see if you understand that string could be treated as sequence of characters. Interviews often have questions not related to real-life programming. I personally hate questions about inheritance tree with `new` modifiers.

Answer (score 12):

Why you need to do it with LINQ, simple string.Replace should do the trick.

```
string str = "21212121".Replace("2","0");
```

EDIT: If you have to use LINQ then may be something like:

```
string  newStr = new string(str.Select(r => (r == '2' ? '0' : r)).ToArray());
```

Comment: @KashifKhan did you consider maybe the interviewer was asking to see what you would say, and maybe the right answer was "LINQ is not the right tool for this job".

Comment: or does it have to do anything with lambda expressions?

Comment: actually, this is a pretty good interview question... would show a fairly solid understanding of Linq and problem solving. Nobody is saying the company would actively use this for string replacement

Comment: Or with cool syntax, `string newStr = new string ((from r in str select r == '2' ? '0' : r).ToArray());` . Don't try it at home!

Comment: @lazyberezovsky, did not consider that the interviewer may have been looking for other qualities in the candidate. Removed, cheers :)

Comment: @Arran yep, interviews sometimes are very strange :) Microsoft used to ask about weight of Boeing, or window cleaners count in the city

Answer (score 1):

For changing a *single* character you can use the [overload of `Replace` that takes `char` arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts.aspx):

```
string s = "21212121";
s = s.Replace('2', '0');
```

This is likely to be slightly more efficient than the overload that accept strings.

---

If you absolutely *have to* use LINQ for some reason, then you can do this:

```
s = new string(s.Select(c => c == '2' ? '0' : c).ToArray());
```

But you shouldn't do this in production code. It's harder to read and less efficient than `string.Replace`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string strInput = "21212121";

char from = '2';
char to = '0';

var strOutput = new string(strInput.Select(c => c.Equals(from) ? to : c)
                                   .ToArray());

Console.WriteLine(strOutput);
```

Comment: I was afraid to do ToArray and all. Is there no other alternative? and is it optimum or still can be optimised?

Comment: ToArray is one way to get the chars in a form which can be passed to the string constructor.